# Dynamic load assembly in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have created a program to load dynamic assemblies using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BarcodeReader
{
   public class Parsing
   {
      private static string _FolderName = "BarcodeReaders";
      private static bool _Initialized = false;
      private static IEnumerable<IBarcodeReader> _Objs;

      /// Parse the picture
      /// <returns>The value from the picture</returns>
      public static async Task<string> ParsePicture()
      {
         // Check if this class has not been initialized, and if it hasn't initialize it
         if (!_Initialized)
         {
            await InitializeAsync();
         }

         foreach (var Obj in _Objs)
         {
            if (Obj.IsType())
            {
               return Obj.GetValue();
            }
         }

         return null;
      }

      private static async Task InitializeAsync()
      {
         // Get the folder
         var Folder = await GetFolder();

         // Get the Files in the Folder
         var Files = await Folder.GetFilesAsync();

         // Initialize the objects and set them
         _Objs = InitializeObjects(Files);

         // Set it as initialized
         _Initialized = true;
      }

      private static IEnumerable<IBarcodeReader> InitializeObjects(IEnumerable<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> Files)
      {
         foreach (var File in Files)
         {
            string Name = File.Path;
            var Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(Name));
            foreach (var Typ in Assembly.ExportedTypes)
            {
               var TypInfo = Typ.GetTypeInfo();
               foreach (var Interf in TypInfo.ImplementedInterfaces)
               {
                  if (Interf.Name.Equals("IBarcodeReader"))
                  {
                     yield return (IBarcodeReader)Activator.CreateInstance(Typ);
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }

      private static async Task<bool> BarcodeFolderExist(Windows.Storage.StorageFolder Folder)
      {
         // Get all folders
         var Folders = await Folder.GetFoldersAsync();

         // For each folder, check if it is the Folder we are searching and if it is return true
         foreach (var Foldr in Folders)
         {
            if (Foldr.Name.Equals(_FolderName))
            {
               return true;
            }
         }

         // Return false as the folder was not found
         return false;
      }

      private static async Task<Windows.Storage.StorageFolder> GetFolder()
      {
         // Get the local-folder
         var Folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

         // Check if the folder does not exist, and if it does not create it
         if (!await BarcodeFolderExist(Folder))
         {
            await Folder.CreateFolderAsync(_FolderName);
         }

         return await Folder.GetFolderAsync(_FolderName);
      }
   }
}
```

And the project I am trying to load is these files

```
namespace QRReader
{
   public sealed class QRReader : IBarcodeReader
   {
      public bool IsType()
      {
         return true;
      }

      public string GetValue()
      {
         return "HEJ";
      }
   }

   public interface IBarcodeReader
   {
      bool IsType();
      string GetValue();
   }
}
```

But I get this error

```
FileLoadException was unhandled by user code
The assembly name or code base was illegal. (Exception HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

The `name`-variable is set to 
`C:\Users\Lasse\AppData\Local\Packages\93e3b2c9-7ef8-4537-be39-d0f3e93ca100_e85ydygyad1dy\LocalState\BarcodeReaders\QRReader.winmd`

Comment: What if you try loading the assembly using reflection ?

Comment: WinRT does not permit loading assemblies from an arbitrary path.  All executables must be packaged together and must be stored in the AppBase folder.  Otherwise an essential feature of an app that is secure and verifiable.  There is thus in general very little point to dynamically loading assemblies.

Comment: @HansPassant I hoped, I could load it, as the thread I have found, said that I was not possible since the Assembly.Load-method was missing

Answer (score 0):

Everything I've read on the internet says that Microsoft have made it a deliberate security feature of the runtime environment (WinRT, and UWP) that it be impossible to load assemblies at runtime. This is a show stopping limiting feature in UWP. It more or less renders the platforms useless because if there are customisations for a given customer, the application vendor would have to split the app and deploy it a version to the store for each customer.

Please take the time to up vote this feature request on allowing assemblies to be loaded dynamically at runtime:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/18145291-dynamically-load-assembly